# Sequelize w/Postgres testing async errors

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, sequelize.js, jestjs

I've been writing unit tests for Sequelize with a Postgres database. For testing, I'm currently using Jest. Right now, I can get this code to work:

```
test('email field only takes valid emails', () => {
  expect.assertions(2);
  let user = Users.build({ email: 'notAProperEmail', password: 'abc123' });
  return user.validate().catch(err => {
    expect(err).toHaveProperty('errors');
    expect(err.errors[0].message).toEqual('Validation isEmail on email failed');
  });
})
```

But for some reason this throws the error "SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Users" does not exist". Also, the expect method also never gets hit because I get the expected assertion error: "Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls."

```
describe('Password is encrypted', () => {
beforeAll(() => {
  Users.create({
    email: 'test1@gmail.com',
    password: 'testPassword123'
  })
});

test('password is not plain text', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  return Users.findOne({where: { email: 'test1@gmail.com' }}).then(response => {
    expect(2).toEqual(2)
    console.log('console log here: ', response);
  });
});
```

My only guess is that because build doesn't actually save to the database, it returns a value in time for Jest to make an assertion. So my intuition is to use promises to handle the async nature (also, I checked the Jest docs). But it still throws this error and it seems like the promises are being returned before Sequelize is done fetching data from my Postgres Database. I'd really appreciate it if someone could shed light on this issue I'm having!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late but I just solved something very similar after landing here!. This is possibly an environment issue. When you run your test suite jest will go looking for the DB that is related to your `test` env no longer your `dev` env. 
In my case i'm using postgres and knex and the different env configs are in the knexFile. I would imagine sequelize is similar!
The way to hunt it down is to run `psql myDBinWhateverEnv` and see if you have a relation "Users"